# Como criar uma aplicação a partir de um arquivo Maven?

Tags: java, java-ee, swing, maven, terminal

Estava eu trabalhando com o EJB e lidando com quatro projetos simples Maven, um projeto web ,um desktop (JSE Swing), um projeto (JSE) que tinha apenas a interface e por ultimo um projeto web (que eu chamei de Core) que implementava esse penúltimo projeto possuidor da interface.
A regra de negocio a principio era bem simples um Hello Brother  que imprimia junto dessa mensagem o nome do usuário que era recebido por parâmetro. Esse era um programa bem simples, que ate uma criança, com um sorriso estampado no rosto conseguiria compreender.
Eu estava usando servidor de aplicções Glassfish . O projeto  "Core" que continha a implementação da regra de negocio era o primeiro a ser implantado e os outros dois consumiam esse serviço através de uma interface remota.
Até aqui tudo bem eu implantei e testei todos eles e deram certo! O Swing , o web  tudo legal !

Moral da historia:

Embora simples deu um certo trabalho para construí-lo, ou seja , tive que criar manualmente um a um, escrevi uma só regra de negocio, o que poupou um tempo considerável, graças ao EJB. O meu professor um sujeito muito bacana criou o mesmo projeto usando o Maven , usando apenas umas três linhas de comando via terminal.
Não tenho a minima ideia do que ele fez! Gostaria de uma explicação de como é possível fazer isso!! Escrevendo apenas a regra de negocio  e o terminal com o Maven!!

Comment: se entendi bem vc quer saber como gerar um projeto com maven? Ou vc quer gerar as regras de negócio com maven também?

Comment: @EmirMarques Obrigado pela atenção cara! O que eu quero é criar  a mesma simples  regra de negócio e gerar os 4 projetos citados na pergunta de um só golpe com o maven, automaticamente!

Comment: Vc quer replicar a regra de negócio em 4 projetos diferentes? Ou quer criar 4 projetos diferentes no mesmo comando?

Comment: Assim um projeto(JSE) fica só com a interface , outro com a implementação(Java web , que eu chamo de core) dessa interface e o outros dois(um projeto web e o outro JSE) , consomem  o serviço  do projeto que implementa a interface,  ambos buscam no projeto core o que eles precisam!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu professor *pode* ter usado um [*Archetype*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) do Maven, isto é, **um arquétipo, protótipo ou modelo de projeto**.

Archetypes são, na verdade, projetos Maven especiais que podem ser usados para gerar projetos Maven.

Um Archetype funciona como um template. É possível inclusive ter variáveis nos arquivos, de forma que ao criar um projeto você informa o valor dessas variáveis e os arquivos são processados com os novos valores.

A grande vantagem de usar Archetypes é ter a estrutura básica de um determinado tipo de projeto sem precisar se atentar para cada detalhe. Isso é particularmente vantajoso para projetos baseados em tecnologias comumente usadas ou para padronizar a criação de projetos em empresas, que podem manter seus Archetypes num repositório interno.

Por outro lado, algumas IDEs como Eclipse, Netbeans e IntelliJ  também possuem alguns modelos de projetos, mas que geralmente não são compatíveis com Maven. Isso gera muita confusão para quem começa usando a estrutura criada pela IDE e depois quer migrar para o Maven ou alguma outra ferramenta de *build*, principalmente porque a estrutura de diretórios geralmente é diferente.

Comment: Obrigado cara ! Por favor , poderia indicar algum tutorial  que ensine a fazer isso?